# How to transform a Word document with images grouped in a Word document with flatten images, without doing steps for each group of images?

Tags: microsoft-word, images, confluence

I need to upload documents in Confluence. My problem is that Conflence charge properly only flatten images, while having problems with the images grouped together.

My documents are in Word and contain a lot of pictures grouped. I need to transform the images grouped in a single image. Seen that the document has many images, I don't want to do this operation on each group of images, but I need to find a way or a tool that transforms the images of the entire document as unique images.

Can you help? I've done many tests, including:

- Convert Word to PDF and again in Word, BUT the images are returned in grouped format
- Convert Word to HTML and upload it to Confluence, BUT Confluence uses TAG specials for referencing images and therefore doesn't recognize them.

Thanks in advance for your collaboration